# Python subprocess - if statement for error

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm just working on basic script for copying a few files from folder to another folder using subprocess. But script ends with error if the file doesn't exists. Is there a way how to handle this error, ignore this file and move to another file?

Below is the code that I tried,

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output("sudo cp /filename.txt ~/folder", shell=True)
    print ("filename.txt" + " - saved")
output = subprocess.check_output("sudo cp /filename2.txt ~/folder", shell=True)
    print ("filename2.txt" + " - saved")
```

In this case the `filename2.txt` doesn't exists, so can i handle the error to say somthing like "filename2.txt - not saved".

Comment: Use `try/except` to catch the error that `check_output` throws when there's an error.

Comment: Why are you using `check_output` in the first place if you don't want it to raise an exception and stop when the command gets an error? Use `subprocess.run` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using try and except will help. In except use pass statement will pass it or you can print your desired one.

```
import subprocess

try:
    output = subprocess.check_output("sudo cp /filename.txt ~/folder", shell=True)
    print ("filename.txt" + " - saved")
except:
    pass
```